# Why is my android studio app skipping the login and registration page when I run it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im developing an android app but when I run the app it is skipping the registration and login page and going straight to the main page.Im using firebase for the authentication and I can't find the problem?

I have tried removing this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this,       MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
```

from

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthStateListener = new 
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth 
    firebaseAuth) {
    final FirebaseUser user = 
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) ;
    {
           Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };
```

And the registration activity opens but it doesn't register me when I  try to register!

this is the RegistrationActivity.java

```
    package com.simoder.tinder;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

    public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button mRegister;
private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) ;
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };


    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthStateListener);
}
}
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.simoder.tinder">



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="tinder"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

<activity android:name=".ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
</application>
```

THIS IS THE RUN LOG

> 08/22 19:19:38: Launching app $ adb shell am start -n
>   "com.simoder.tinder/com.simoder.tinder.ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity"
>   -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online Connected to
>   process 6929 on device emulator-5554 Capturing and displaying logcat
>   messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the
>   "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page. V/FA:
>   Registered activity lifecycle callback W/DynamiteModule: Local module
>   descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful V/FA:
>   onActivityCreated W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found. W/.simoder.tinde: Accessing hidden
>   method
>   Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
>   (light greylist, reflection) W/.simoder.tinde: Accessing hidden method
>   Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light
>   greylist, reflection) I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to
>   create service connection to gms implementation D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia
>   GL Pipeline D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established
>   0xe7426d40, tid 6966 I/ConfigStore:
>   android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay
>   retrieved: 0
>       android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay
>   retrieved: 0 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose
>   config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext:
>   0xe8d05660: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xe8d05660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8d03bb0) V/FA: Collection enabled
>       App package, google app id: com.simoder.tinder, 1:361954020021:android:e29700d74fee181e D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8d05660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8d03bb0) I/FA: App
>   measurement is starting up, version: 18102
>       To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>       To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
>         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.simoder.tinder D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled V/FA:
>   Connecting to remote service I/.simoder.tinde: Background concurrent
>   copying GC freed 33445(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(568KB) LOS objects,
>   50% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 5.099ms total 122.920ms V/FA: Connection
>   attempt already in progress I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus
>   will not be used D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5627487735175610182}] V/FA: Connection
>   attempt already in progress V/FA: Connection attempt already in
>   progress V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 3469652 D/FA: Connected to
>   remote service V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4 V/FA:
>   Recording user engagement, ms: 2121 W/ActivityThread:
>   handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token
>   android.os.BinderProxy@3ad9909 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 3471749
>   V/FA: onActivityCreated D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   engagement_time_msec(_et)=2121,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5627487735175610182}] D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8d05660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8d03bb0) D/FA: Logging
>   event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-5627487735175610182,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegistrationActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2870007480556052360}] D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8d05660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8d03bb0)
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8d05660: ver 3 0 (tinfo
>   0xe8d03bb0) W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@c00c693 V/FA: onActivityCreated V/FA:
>   Activity resumed, time: 3471960 V/FA: Screen exposed for less than
>   1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 240 V/FA: Activity paused, time:
>   3472114 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs),
>   Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto,
>   firebase_previous_class(_pc)=RegistrationActivity,
>   firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-2870007480556052360,
>   firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity,
>   firebase_screen_id(_si)=-2870007480556052359}] D/EGL_emulation:
>   eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8d05660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8d03bb0) V/FA: Activity
>   resumed, time: 3472218 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the
>   service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be from this line of code

```
  if(user != null)
```

Try to remove that line of code and try again. I ran into a similar problem when following a pluralsight tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your AndroidManifest.xml file, you will have to set the activity in which you want to display first as the Launcher Activity like this:

```
 <activity android:name=".FirstActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        ...
 </activity>
<activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity">
          <intent-filter>
           //This is what you'll need to add to the activity you want
           // to come up first 
            **<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />**
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: hey I added the AndroidManifest.xml check it out

Comment: no its not its still skipping the login/register page

Comment: Oh, the problem is not from the manifest, if the user is logged in, as stated in your code if (user != null) then it should start the Activity which it seems to be doing. try uninstalling and reinstalling the app and observe what happens

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` from if statement in your Registration Activity

```
if (user != null) ; //remove this ; from here
{
       Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, 
MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
```